# Driver recording in openMDAO

Tags: sqlite, driver, openmdao, recorder

I have the following code to record the driver cases:

```
recorder = om.SqliteRecorder('cases.sql')
prob.driver.add_recorder(recorder)

...

prob.run_driver()

...

cr = om.CaseReader("cases.sql")

driver_cases = cr.get_cases('driver', recurse=False)
last_case = cr.get_case(driver_cases[-1])
```

I'm getting the following error on last line:

> cur.execute("SELECT * FROM driver_iterations WHERE "
> sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter :iteration_coordinate - probably unsupported type.

What may be the reason?

Comment: which line of code is causing that sql error? is it from the recording or the reading?

Comment: the last line: last_case = cr.get_case(driver_cases[-1])

Answer (score 0):

Once you have `driver_cases`, obtained from the `get_cases` method you can simply issue

```
last_case = driver_cases[-1]
```

Alternatively, you can use `cr.list_cases()` to list the cases that way, which returns a string identifier for each case.  Passing that string to `get_case` should then give you what you want.

```
cases = cr.list_cases('driver')
last_case = cr.get_case(cases[-1])
```

Comment: Thanks! In the end I'm using `prob.record("final_state")` right after `prob.run_driver()` to get the final case directly.